# passing \n (new line) on stdout throught sys argument

Tags: python, stdout

This is elementary I guess:

Let's consider this snippet:

```
for i in range(3):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

out:

```
0
1
2
```

and this:

```
for i in range(3):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i) + sys.argv[1])
```

out (after passing \n as argument):

```
0\n1\n2\n
```

So, how can I pass new-line as argument?

Comment: windows?if so i think u should pass `'\n\r'`

Comment: @Ghostly, perhaps it is easier to append `\n` to `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: yes, it's windows, but it's same unfortunately after with `'\n\r'`

Comment: Do you want to pass a literal newline, or a backslash-n that your program treats as a newline? Those are two different problems with two different solutions.

Comment: @Mike: I need to pass it as argument - it's just very simplified part of crazy script

Comment: @Bryan: I just need to output with new-line on CLI, as in first snippet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sys.stdout.write(str(i) + sys.argv[1].decode("string_escape"))
```